# Looping through a sequence of calculations and print number of iterations

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to loop through a calculation using the following equation:

[image: Equation image]

where alpha is a positive number that controls the growth rate and K is a positive number that defines the capacity, i.e., the maximum number of bacteria in the population.

The script should simulate the bacteria growth hour by hour and stops when the number of bacteria exceeds
some fixed number, N. Your program must return the time t at which the population first exceeds N.

I am a bit lost and thinking whether to use *for* or a *while* loop.

My starting point is the following template:

```
def bacteriaGrowth(n0, alpha, K, N):

 return tN
```

I expect the output to be a single integer as can be seen on following example:

[image: Example image]

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried?
Also using a while or a for mostly depends on if you need to count before the loop or after the contents of the loop are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that does what you want, along with the test case given in your second graphic. The result is `7`, as it is supposed to be. Running the code through a debugger shows that `nt` gets the appropriate value in each loop (rounded to one decimal place), a shown in that second graphic.

You use a `while` loop when you do not know how many times the loop will be executed. Since your loop updates the value of `nt` and you want to find the number of times the loop is executed until `nt` becomes larger than `N`, you do not know the number of loops so you use a `while` loop.

```
def bacteriaGrowth(n0, alpha, K, N):
    tN = 0
    nt = n0
    while nt <= N:
        nt = (1 + alpha * (1 - nt / K)) * nt
        tN += 1
    return tN

print(bacteriaGrowth(100.0, 0.4, 1000.0, 500.0))
```

Comment: Why publish the direct solution, when the problem is clearly about homework, and the question about the way to go?